# PIVOT Multiple columns in tsql

Tags: pivot-table

I have a table that is constructed like this

```
custid|prodid|calls|orders|upsell
 34   |   2  |   4 |   2  |   1
```

However i need to Pivot or reconstruct to table to reflect something like

```
custid|prodid|code   |Value
34    |   2  | call  | 4
34    |   2  | order | 2
34    |   2  | upsell| 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a union approach:

```
SELECT custid, prodid, 'call' AS code, calls AS [Value] FROM yourTable UNION
SELECT custid, prodid, 'order', orders FROM yourTable UNION
SELECT custid, prodid, 'upsell', upsell FROM yourTable;
```